# playframework 2 module and logs to output

Tags: scala, module, playframework-2.0

I'v followed [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-modules-play-2-get) tutorial

to make Scala Plaframework application work with depending module that has 'println' message in it.

So, 
 myApp depends on myModule, in myMyModule' controller I have:

```
object MyLogger {

  def log(message: String) {
    Console.println("something" + message)
  }

}
```

In myApp I have:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    MyLogger.log("Here's my log message");

    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

I go to localhost:9000, and I'm expecting 'Here's my log message' to be in my output, **but there is no any**, except:

> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
>
> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

I' have checked:

1. *cd myApp;*
2. *play dependencies* (myApp it really depends on myModule, so it should work)

**--**

After some investigation I found that until I delete dependency to myDev, this message 'this is an info' in MyApp index controller was not showed as well. And then, when I delete that dependency, the application stars reacting to my changes again:

```
def index = Action {

    play.api.Logger.info("this is an info")

    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready!"))
  }
```

So, maybe I defined my module using wrong way. Should I change the structure of the myModule? or it is possible to leave it like a default project structure? I will check it later. I guess the reason is with 'routes' file wich I leave in my MyModule.

Comment: Do you see the "index" page itself?

Comment: yes. there is default one. green one.

Comment: Actually if I change the 'Your new application is ready.' to anything else it does not update the message on the page.. I guess it might be the reason. (even after 'play clean' for myApp)

Comment: You started application with `play start` ? use `play run` instead or restart the app (`run` is better while developing)

Comment: I use 'play run' for all my tries

Comment: WHEN i deleted dependency to 'myModule' it starts show me messages which I defined in MyApp index controller.

Answer (score 2):

Why won't you use [play.api.Logger](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/play/api/Logger.html) ?

It allows you to log to the different levels - depending on your `application.conf` and app mode settings:

```
def index = Action {
    play.api.Logger.info("this is an info")
    play.api.Logger.debug("and debug is also possible")
    play.api.Logger.error("...and error")
    play.api.Logger.warn("or even warn")
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}
```

`dev` mode displays all levels by default and `life` will avoid displaying the `debug`

Comment: this is reasonable. but does not work for me. It even does not work if put these lines to myApp index controller.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I had this problem, is because myModule was an application, but not a module. I had to:

1. delete 'routes' file
2. clean up 'application.conf' file
3. delete 'views' folder

   Then I can call this a module, but not application.

I guess it woud be better If play has something like this: play newModule. Maybe it has?

(So, I just missed this part about 'routes', that actually was described in the tutorial above. Too lazy to read.. :(. Play framework 1.x works similar to that, regarding the modules. )